# How to perform segue with no transition animation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard

I have an application which starts with a navigation controller. This navigation controller can open modal view controller:

```
- (void)openModalController:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier"];
}
```

But when the user opens an application using url scheme, I'd like to present the application with the modal controller opened. So I added some methods and tried:

```
// Controller

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; // animated == NO in initial loading 

    if (_shouldOpenModalController) {
        [self openModalController:nil];
    }
}

- (void)setShouldOpenModalController:(BOOL)flag
{
    _shouldOpenModalController = flag;
}

// AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions) {
        UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        MyViewController *c = (MyViewController *)[ns topViewController];
        [c setShouldOpenModalController];
    }
}
```

But here is a problem: the `openModalController:` performs segue with transition animation I setup in storyboard. How can it be done with no animation? Is there another approach for this task?

Comment: Subclass `UISegue` and override `perform`.

Comment: @Martol1ni next time I will want to open it with animation... By now I'm using `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` but I don't think this is the best solution

Comment: You are using segues, right?

Comment: Mmmm... Yes... But to skip the storyboard to the place I need now I am using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. So one time I configure the controller in `prepareForSegue:sender:` other time I should configure it in other place so I don't like it. Should I just drop using segues for this controller?

Comment: I would drop the segue. Personally I find my self dropping them more often than not. Primarily because I don't like do the setup in the `prepareForSegue:` method either. I do use the storyboard to setup the interface though and instantiate them via `instatiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Duplicate your segue in Storyboard and give the second one a different ID.

You can then change the transition in the new version.

Comment: To create one more segue to try to skip the transition animation on it...  There must be other way, I'd rather open view controller manually than create custom segue transition with no animation.

Comment: You don't need a custom segue, there is an 'animates' checkbox on the modal transition.

Comment: Trying to create a new segue between the same view and VC only replace the existing segue... at least on Xcode 6.1 (not using size-classes)

Answer (score 39):

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue",sender: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue of supporting two flow scenarios, one with animation and one without.

Answer (score 9):

I am using this snippet to request authorization in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
self.view.hidden = YES;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_auth" sender:self];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.4 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    self.view.hidden = NO;
});
```

When authorized, back transition is animated as I want.

Comment: This solution works in Xcode 6+, and others don't (segue duplication is not allowed).

Comment: @ruliak I am not duplicating segue. I think you wanna comment not this answer :)

Comment: I wish I could vote twice. I've come back here a year later and used this method again! Forgot that I'd found it once already!

Comment: I just would add this: wrap up the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` message with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: */ });` prevents the warning: *"Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ..."*.

Answer (score 6):

One more way we can

```
YourViewController *aYourViewController = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aYourViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aYourViewController animated:NO];
```

and add the `@"aYourViewControllerIdentifier"` to view controller in your storyboard.

Comment: This is more of a hastle. If we already have a segue, we shouldnt be instantiating the view controller by code. The whole point of having a segue is to avoid instantiating the view controller in the code.